# Netsuite CASE WHEN expression in custom search is returning “invalid expression”

Tags: case, netsuite

Can someone help me with what is wrong with this expression

```
case When ({item.locationquantitybackordered} > 0 AND {quantitycommitted} > 0) 
Then ({item.locationquantitybackordered}+{quantitycommitted})
Else
when {item.locationquantitybackordered} > 0
Then {quantitycommitted} = 0
Else {item.locationquantitybackordered} = 0
{item.locationquantitybackordered}+{quantitycommitted}
End
End
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there are a few things I would fix on this.

First, you don't need `ELSE` before `WHEN`. There should only be one `WHEN`, at the end of the `CASE` statement as the last condition.

Second, you have two `END` statements, which isn't necessary - only one is needed per `CASE` statement. You might need one if you had a nested `CASE` statement, but you don't so it is unnecessary.

Finally, your `ELSE` actually doesn't make much sense - you have two statements in there, `{item.locationquantitybackordered} = 0` (which is a test, not a value) and `{item.locationquantitybackordered} + {quantitycommitted}`, which is a proper value, and it is the same as your first case above.

I'd rewrite your statement as:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ({item.locationquantitybackordered} > 0 AND {quantitycommitted} > 0) THEN ({item.locationquantitybackordered} + {quantitycommitted})
    WHEN {item.locationquantitybackordered} > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE {item.locationquantitybackordered} + {quantitycommitted}
END
```